# How to do the simplest pagination in GraphQL? (using Star War API)

Tags: graphql

I was able to find how to get the first N or last N elements:

```
{
 allPeople(first: 2) {
   people {
     name
     birthYear
   }
 }
}
```

(It can be tested on https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql or https://studio.apollographql.com/public/star-wars-swapi/variant/current/explorer)

However, it is typical that some websites use

> [www.my-site.com/people?page=3](http://www.my-site.com/people?page=3)

as a bookmark to see page 3 of the results.

For example, the Star War API has 82 people (actors / actresses), so let's say if I show 5 persons per page, then I may have a URL

> [www.my-site.com/people?page=12](http://www.my-site.com/people?page=12)

and let users send this URL to their friends.  The solution I see to do pagination is to use a `cursor`, so will it work for getting page 12 directly?  If it involves getting results 12 times (each time using a cursor to get the next 5 records), then it seems it is not efficient.

Is there a simple way to do it?

P.S. if I remember correctly, if the underlying DB is relational DB, then there is no SQL statements that says: "fetch me records 1000000 to 1000050", because there is no "ordering by number" or "percentage of records" concept such as "give me records of 50% to 52% percentile." However, if there are just small amount of records, like the number 82 above or 220 total, I think the method is to get all records, and then return either 5 or 10 to the web client, so that instead of sending all 82 records, it is enough just to send 5.

Comment: Can you just directly expose the GraphQL endpoint to your end users, instead of trying to bridge between a query-string-type API to GraphQL?

Answer (score 1):

For this particular demo API you will need to use the `cursor` and fetch the next set of records until you reach the page you want to display.

This demo API is more suitable for an *infinite scroll* type of pagination than a paged one since you can always get the next set of records based on where you are.

When you build your own app you can define your own pagination style in the back end based on the needs of your front end. If you want numbered, bookmarkable pages and you're using MySQL then you could use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` to [directly access the records you want](https://planetscale.com/blog/mysql-pagination) however this approach has [certain limitations](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/).

Comment: do you know if the `OFFSET` is efficient? I suppose it should, or else if you have 1 billion records and you want record 500000 to 500050, does it need to go through all the first 499999 leaf nodes before getting the 500000th record? If it was 20 or 25 years ago, I remember the DBMS really needed to, if I am not mistaken. But maybe RDBMS advanced a bit so that you can get the Nth record efficiently nowadays

Comment: It really depends on the underlying DB. As that second article points out, OFFSET can be both inefficient and inaccurate. That being said, a UI design that encourages the user to jump ahead 500k records is going to have terrible usability issues - that's page 5,000 at 100 records/page. Normally you'll want to filter records down to a more manageable set before letting the user page through them.

Comment: I should add that links that include pagination information may not be very useful for sharing - the content of a given page will change as the underlying records change.

Comment: so if it is using a cursor, isn't it true that for the Page 1 2 3 4 5, Prev Next, the Page 1 can be implemented, the Next can be implemented, and then 2, 3, 4, 5, cannot be easily implemented, and Prev is complicated to implement, if you somehow memorize what the previous cursors were. So maybe the Star War API isn't a great source for pagination

Comment: I was finally able to do something with "offset pagination", at https://graphql-pokeapi.graphcdn.app/ using `{ pokemons(limit: 3, offset: 130) { results { id name } } }` I wonder why no other book or intro / tutorial made it so easy to try this out

Answer (score 0):

I also was able to find more answers:

There are two types of paginations:

1. Offset pagination
2. Cursor pagination

The server has to be set up so that you can use it.

For example, on https://graphql-pokeapi.graphcdn.app/

I was able to use

```
{
  pokemons(limit: 3, offset: 130) {
    results {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

and be able to get

```json
{
  "data": {
    "pokemons": {
      "results": [
        {
          "id": 131,
          "name": "lapras"
        },
        {
          "id": 132,
          "name": "ditto"
        },
        {
          "id": 133,
          "name": "eevee"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can try different offset and limit to experiment with it. With this, the traditional

```
Page: Prev 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Next
```

can be supported, and so can the URL having a `?page=5` so that you can send somebody the URL and be able to see page 5.

Comment: Just know that the results of "page 5" (or of any page) are subject to change.